# Wrong output, but Correct Equation - Division using user input

Tags: android, android-studio, division

I am trying to make a simple conversion app. I am being returned an incorrect number for my code. The equation looks like 16/16 which should be =1. It is returning me with 1.3 and some more numbers. Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong? Below is my code if you want to take a look at it. **My inputs for the app was 16 ounces to lb.** I appreciate any insight available.

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.831"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.471" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:background="#E6E6E6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.831"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.309" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:text="@string/convert"
        app:backgroundTint="#3C3838"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.598" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.651"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.323"
        tools:text="Enter Amount" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textAnswer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Conversion"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.138" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Main**:

```
package com.stproductions.commonconverter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView[] txtAnswer = {findViewById(R.id.textAnswer)};
        txtAnswer[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        double enterAnswer = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(R.id.enterAmount));


        //Convert From Box
        Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fromchoices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);


        //Convert To Box
        Spinner spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

                    //   oz    lb      g       kg         ton        mg
        double[] ounce = {1, 0.0625, 28.35, 0.0283495, 0.00003125, 28349.5};
        double[] pound = {16, 1, 453.59, 0.453592, 0.0005, 453592};
        double[] gram = {0.35274, 0.0022, 1, 0.001, 0.000001, 1000};
        double[] kilogram = {35.274, 2.2, 1000, 1, 0.00110231, 1000000};
        double[] ton = {32000, 2000, 907185, 907.185, 1, 907184740};
        double[] milligram = {0.000035, 0.000002, 0.001, 0.0000001, 0.000000001, 1};


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (spinner1.getSelectedItem() != null && spinner2.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    String first_option = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String second_option = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    if (first_option.contentEquals("oz") && second_option.contentEquals("lb")) {

                        double finishConversion = enterAnswer / pound[0];
                        String str = Double.toString(finishConversion);

                        txtAnswer[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        txtAnswer[0].setText(str);

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Strings**:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Common Converter</string>
    <string name="convert">Convert</string>

    <string-array name="choices">
            <item>lb</item>
            <item>oz</item>
            <item>g</item>
            <item>kg</item>
            <item>ton</item>
            <item>mg</item>
        </string-array>

    <string-array name="fromchoices">
        <item>lb</item> 
        <item>oz</item> 
        <item>g</item> 
        <item>kg</item> 
        <item>ton</item> 
        <item>mg</item> 
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about a change to the following

```
double enterAnswer = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(R.id.enterAmount));

to

EditText amount = findViewById(R.id.enterAmount)
double enterAnswer = Double.parseDouble(enterAnswer.getText());
```

I'm pretty sure the rest of your code it's OK, so I think `String.valueOf(R.id.enterAmount)` Is giving you a weird value.

Comment: I've been messing around with all of that. Is there anyway you might be able to plug it in to my code on your end and share it here? It keeps giving me errors. Forgive me as well, I am somewhat new to coding so I have a limited understanding!

Comment: You can put your code on github.com and it will be my pleasure to help you.